# Apache Drill: Two Lateral Joins with Array Fails Only With Storage Plugins

Tags: apache-drill

Hitting a bit of a wall with Apache Drill, when we query the following where the JSON is selected from a string using convertFromJSON, the query works(if you paste this into a Query window on drill it will work):

```
SELECT
    t_items.item['secName'] as SecurityName
FROM
    --dfs.tmp.`4.json` a, 
( Select convert_fromjson('{
   "data":{
    "RefAccountAll": [
      {
        "valuations":[ 
          { 
            "securityValuations": [{"secName":"abc"},{"secName":"def"}]
        }]
    }]
  }
}') as a) t,    
    
LATERAL
    ( SELECT  c1.v.valuations as vals1 FROM
UNNEST
    (t.a.data.RefAccountAll) c1(v)
    ) t_orders
   ,
LATERAL
    (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(t_orders.vals1.securityValuations) _items(item) ) t_items
```

If I perform the same query but with the same JSON in a file (dfs.tmp.`4.json`), Apache Drill SQL query returns the following error:

***org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to get new vector for minor type [LATE] and mode [OPTIONAL]***

I can run other queries no problem (with the JSON in a file) but only hit this when the JSON is in a file. In the case where it blows up "c1.v.valuations" is coming up as [], but when I run it with JSON inline right in the query
"c1.v.valuations" has a nice value.

Any ideas or assistance here?  You help would be so appreciated!

Thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that Drill seems to be using different reader settings for the `ConvertFROMJSON` function than reading the raw JSON.

I'm wondering however, if there might be a better way of querying this data using Drill's native nested functions rather than the JOINS?  Do you have a small sample file you could share?